# Begineer Phonebook

Tags: c, pointers

Hey just started getting into code last week. Can anyone tell me what is wrong with my code? When I compile it it seems to work but when I go to my file there I just a bunch of question marks. Ex(Name:D...)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file= fopen("phonebook.csv", "a");

    if(file==NULL) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char* name= malloc(sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter your name:");
    scanf("%s", name);

    free(name);

    char* number= realloc(name, sizeof(char));
    printf("Enter your number:");
    scanf("%s", number);

    free(number);

    fprintf(file, "Name: %s\n, Number:%s\n", name, number );

    fclose(file);
}
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(char))` allocates memory for a single byte of memory. You can't read someone's name into a single byte. The same applies to your `realloc` call.

Comment: Also using thing after passing them to `free()` is bad.

Comment: Also note that `%s` stops reading at whitespace characters and thus "your name" cannot contain whitespace characters.

Answer (score 1):

Critical mistakes:

- You will need multiple bytes to store positive-length strings. On the other hand, you are allocating only one byte.
- `realloc()` is to change length of existing buffer. In this case, you should allocate independent another buffer in this case.
- You must not use pointers passed to `free()`.

Other points:

- You should limit length to read to avoid buffer overflow.
  The size limit should be at most `(buffer size) - 1` (`-1` for terminating null-character).
- You should check the results of `malloc()`.
- You should check the results of `scanf()`.

Fixed code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file= fopen("phonebook.csv", "a");

    if(file==NULL) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char* name= malloc(sizeof(char) * 129);

    if(name==NULL) 
    {
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter your name:");
    if(scanf("%128s", name)!=1)
    {
        fclose(file);
        free(name);
        return 1;
    }

    char* number= malloc(sizeof(char) * 129);

    if(number==NULL) 
    {
        free(name);
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    printf("Enter your number:");
    if(scanf("%128s", number)!=1)
    {
        free(name);
        free(number);
        fclose(file);
        return 1;
    }

    fprintf(file, "Name: %s\n, Number:%s\n", name, number );

    free(name);
    free(number);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Fixed code (without error checking):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int main(void)
{
    FILE *file= fopen("phonebook.csv", "a");

    if(file==NULL) 
    {
        return 1;
    }

    char* name= malloc(sizeof(char) * 129);
    printf("Enter your name:");
    scanf("%128s", name);

    char* number= malloc(sizeof(char) * 129);
    printf("Enter your number:");
    scanf("%128s", number);

    fprintf(file, "Name: %s\n, Number:%s\n", name, number );

    free(name);
    free(number);

    fclose(file);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing this with less lines of code is ... ( char * is just like using a string data type(since string is not in C)).

```
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    //open file
    FILE *file = fopen("phonebook.csv", "a");
    //get string from user
    char *name = get_string("Name: ");
    char *number = get_string("Number: ");
    //Print (write) strings to file
    fprintf(file, "%s,%s\n", name, number);
    //closing file
    fclose(file);
}
```